# How to pass a parameter inside command button in jsf method?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

on jsp side my code is like:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{selectMenuBean.getSelectedMenu(menu) }" value="#{menu.menuId }" >
                        <f:param value="#{menu.menuId }"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
```

in bean class I have a method:-

```
public String updateSelectedMenu( String menuId)
{
    for (SpecificMenuDetail specificMenuDetail : specificMenu) {
        if((specificMenuDetail.getMenuId()==Integer.parseInt(menuId)))
                {
                    specificMenuDetail.setMaxPrice(toModifyMenu.getMaxPrice());
                }
    }
    return "success";
}
```

this method will accept the value when we click on a specific link inside the jsp page and redirects it to success page but it is giving me this in console:-

type Exception report

message java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
"com.infy.bean.SpecificMenuDetail@b8fbb9"

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF/JSP. Check the value of `menuId` to see whether it can be parsed to a number or not. It should be here `Integer.parseInt(menuId)` in the given code snippet.

Comment: Why do you pass `#{menu.menuId }` inside `<f:param>` if you already have this variable in backing bean? Parameter `menu` is a `String` created from object of type `SpecificMenuDetail ` and you want to cast it to `Integer` hence exception. Also don't compare `Integer`s with `==`, use `Integer.compare(int x, int y)`.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` returns `int` - a primitive type. Therefore, it is perfectly legit to use `==` in this case.